# How to fetch the "HREF" link from email content using javax mail?

Tags: java, selenium

Scenario: I need to click on the registration link from gmail via javax mail.

Here my scenario is I need to separate href content from the whole mail content which we fetch using inspect the element.

From the below picture, I am getting the whole html tag for "Getting Started Today" link using inspect the element.

Inspect Element of Getting Started Today link:

```
https://u9738139.ct.sendgrid.net/ls/click?upn=BPEdlQPL1bTBzMFJ4T-2FMSCLqyVGH4nH5Cfahbthey41XetxY34HDkr5T5zC4sod3uaKeK1sQ2hv3M8UWc0NU3Isz-2BeKa5UsULu9-2BP4LsdIee-2B67fC7jeXcHr1-2B6Nk7slXqar_cKXYbNIReP0b0mWRGpcgiH39UX-2BY091vJss-2F-2BFxybEmov93OKh5iqnOTsasYycySJEisyJxL-2FH3KxF0AqK76x5GNPM3X-2BczMI499TE-2FdRCi8AvcFbI9P3kemV1Cr-2BOQx3UHM0t5EVj4MOXcGk0jdl-2Bn80JT8bY3WlJj9EgQeCGNF1y1eNtROlvSfI3aEuUTCl1UicfnUgpNy2fSJrtGsxNBHSbVHrpTml-2FTO-2F6jUHBc-3D

Now when I try to fetch the whole content of "Getting started Today" email, i got the below value:
```

3D"https://u9738139.ct.sendgrid.net/ls/click?upn=3DBPEdlQPL1bTBzMF=J4T-2FMSCLqyVGH4nH5Cfahbthey41XetxY34HDkr5T5zC4sod3uaKeK1sQ2hv3M8UWc0NU3Isz=-2BeKa5UsULu9-2BP4LsdIee-2B67fC7jeXcHr1-2B6Nk7slXqar_cKXYbNIReP0b0mWRGpcgiH=39UX-2BY091vJss-2F-2BFxybEmov93OKh5iqnOTsasYycySJEisyJxL-2FH3KxF0AqK76x5GNP=M3X-2BczMI499TE-2FdRCi8AvcFbI9P3kemV1Cr-2BOQx3UHM0t5EVj4MOXcGk0jdl-2Bn80JT8=bY3WlJj9EgQeCGNF1y1eNtROlvSfI3aEuUTCl1UicfnUgpNy2fSJrtGsxNBHSbVHrpTml-2FTO-=2F6jUHBc-3D"

Now I am able to retrieve the href link from the email but when i compare both the above HREF(From inspect element and extracted via javax mail), extra characters like "3D" "=" are appended. So while trying the click the link it is showing wrong link.

So I need a solution like

1. I need to retrieve from inspecting element via Javax Mail.

Kindly suggest a solution to resolve the issue.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRSUX.png)
Thanks,

Comment: Please format the code in your post. [See how to do that here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Can you reformulate your question please? I just understood that you want to retrieve the HREF reference via "javax mail", can't you just retrieve it using selenium and then pass it to the first api?

Answer (score 0):

**Get the content and then use ReGex to parse the URL from String content:**

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b(http|https)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(stringToSearch);
String foundUrl = "";
while (matcher.find()) {
  int matchStart = matcher.start(1);
  int matchEnd = matcher.end();
  foundUrl = stringToSearch.substring(matchStart, matchEnd);
}
System.out.println(foundUrl);
```

**Another way to parse URL from HTML:**

```
String stringToSearch = "<p>An http://example.com/'><b>example</b></a> link.</p>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(stringToSearch);
String link = doc.select("a").attr("href");
System.out.println(link);
```